# Get attribute from object in list of objects created by loop

Tags: python, loops, object, indexing, attributes

I create multiple objects of a class `Student`, by using a loop and saving them in the list `object_list`.

Now I want to create a function, which gives me back one specific attribute of a certain object from the `object list`. For example the attribute "name" of the third created object.

Perhaps it is possible to do this with the `getattr()` function, but the problem is that every created object is called the same ("Student").

Is there a way to index the object description "Student" while creating them in the loop, like `Student_1`, `Student_2`, `Student_3`?

This is my code in which I create the objects:

```
# Definition of the class Student
class Student(object):
    name = ""
    degree = ""
    grade = ""
    
    def __init__(self, name, degree, grade):
        self.name = name
        self.degree = degree
        self.grade = grade


object_list = []

# Create objects
def create_objects(data):
    x = 0

    # Loop through lists of data
    for list in data[1:]:
        x = x + 1
        # Get values from data to instantiate objects
        object_list.append(Student(get_value(data, x, 0), get_value(data, x, 1), get_value(data, x, 2))

    return object_list
```

Now I want to create a function I can use like this:

```
get_attribute(object_list, "Student_3", "name")
```

How do I call a specific object from the `object_list`?

Comment: Your example code doesn't include the contents of `data`, which makes it hard to provide a complete solution.  If the problem is that the names you're getting from `data` are all the same and you want them to be different, that's a different problem from selecting the resulting object that has a particular name.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to define your attributes at the class level as well as the instance level:

```
# Definition of the class Student
class Student(object):
    # no class attributes
    def __init__(self, name, degree, grade):
        # these are all instance attributes
        self.name = name
        self.degree = degree
        self.grade = grade
```

An easy way to get an object matching certain criteria from a list is to use a filter, which you can do with the `filter()` function or by just putting an `if` in a comprehension:

```
>>> object_list = [Student("Bob", "first", "A"), Student("Biff", "second", "B"), Student("Betty", "third", "C")]
>>> [s for s in object_list if s.name == "Biff"]
[<__main__.Student object at 0x000001855B7D2D60>]
>>> [s for s in object_list if s.name == "Biff"][0].degree
'second'
```

If you want to use the name of the attribute as a string, you can indeed use `getattr`:

```
>>> [s for s in object_list if getattr(s, "name") == "Biff"][0].degree
'second'
```

If you're doing something like that, though, you probably want to use a regular `dict` instead of an object:

```
>>> def student(name, degree, grade):
...     return {"name": name, "degree": degree, "grade": grade}
...
>>> object_list = [student("Bob", "first", "A"), student("Biff", "second", "B"), student("Betty", "third", "C")]
>>> [s for s in object_list if s["name"] == "Biff"]
[{'name': 'Biff', 'degree': 'second', 'grade': 'B'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_attribute(obj_list, index, attribute):
    return getattr(obj_list[index], attribute)

# Gets the name of the 3rd student created
get_attribute(object_list, 3, "name")
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all I recommend you to use an enumeration. You don't need to iterate with the x manually. Second you can concatenate multiple strings and init your student.

```
    for idx, list in enumerate(data[1:]):
        #You dont need x anymore


        name = str(get_value(data, x, 0)) + str(idx) #Append the Number of the index
        degree = get_value(data, x, 1)
        grade = get_value(data, x, 2)

        object_list.append(Student(name, degree, grade)
```

You can implement the Function just like you said with getattr()

```
    def get_attribute(list, value, attribute):

        for object in list:
            if getattr(object, attribute) == value:
                return object

        #If nothing has the name
        return None
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary to solve your problem instead of a list.

You simply create a new dictionary key with the `x` iterated value.

```
object_dict = {}

# Create objects
def create_objects(data):
    x = 0

    # Loop through lists of data
    for list in data[1:]:
        x = x + 1
       
        # Get values from data to instantiate objects
        object_dict['Student_' + str(x)] = Student(get_value(data, x, 0), get_value(data, x, 1), get_value(data, x, 2))

    return object_dict
```

Now as far as the `get_attribute(object_list, "Student_3", "name")` function. It could look something like this.

```
def get_attribute(object_dict, student, attribute):
  student_num = object_dict[student]
  return student_num.attribute
```

Hope this helps!! Happy coding!